# What will be the name of table created, after creating a module/widget in SocialEngine?

Tags: php, database, module, socialengine

1. I've gone to admin panel
2. Packages and Plugins
3. Developer SDK tab
4. Selected 'Create a Package'
5. Set Type to Module
6. Name: test-module
7. Title: Test Module
   ...
8. Selected 'Create Package'
9. Gone to Manage Packages tab
10. Selected Install New Packages
11. Uploaded the created, modified, compressed tar file

My question is: **What will be the name of table created for my module/widget?**

Comment: When you create module from admin panel. You have to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your table manually. Usually pattern is following: `engine4_modulename_entityname`.